# Convolution theorem for other transforms

Tags: fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

The Fourier transform is an integral transform with turns any function into a superposition of sinusoidal waves. The convolution theorem states the astonishing property that if you convolve two functions, this is equivalent to simply multiplying the corresponding transformed functions. Since the inverse Fourier transform is nearly identical to the Fourier transform, it is perhaps unsurprising that the same holds in the other direction.

Do *all* integral transforms have this fascinating property? Or is it unique to the Fourier transform? (And if the Fourier transform is the only integral transform in all existence that has this property, *why is that?*)

Comment: Correction:"The convolution theorem states the astonishing property that if you convolve two functions, this is equivalent to" should be "The convolution theorem states *the Fourier transform* of the convolution of two functions is *equal to*"

Comment: You should read about commutative Banach algebras and the Gelfand transform.

Comment: Multiplication of polynomials is done by convolution of the two sequences of coefficients. And the method of multiplication of positive integers expressed in base-10 that is taught in elementary school is a sort of convolution of the sequence of digits.

Answer (score 7):

The answer depends on how you define convolution.  For example,
consider (real-valued) vectors
$$x = \bigr (x[{\bf 0}], x[{\bf 1}], \ldots x[{\bf 2^n-1}]\bigr)$$
of length $2^n$ with $x[{\bf i}]$ being thought of not as the $i$-th element,
$0 \leq i \leq 2^n-1$, but rather as the element in the $\bf i$-th position where
$\bf i$ is the $n$-bit standard binary representation of $i$.
Then, the term-by-term product of the Walsh-Hadamard transforms $xH$ and $yH$
of $x$ and $y$ respectively is the Walsh-Hadamard
transform of their *convolution* which is defined as
$$(x \star y)[{\bf k}] = \sum_{{\bf m}} x[{\bf m}]y[{\bf k} \oplus {\bf m}]$$
where the sum is over all binary $n$-tuples $\bf m$.  Here $H$ is the
$2^n\times 2^n$ Hadamard matrix in the Sylvester form.

On the other hand, the Walsh-Hadamard transform does not support the "usual"
cyclic convolution $\displaystyle (x\star y)[k] = \sum_\ell x[\ell]y[k-\ell]$ of vectors where $k-l$ would be interpreted modulo $2^n$.

Comment: Is that the same as the one mentioned here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_transform#Multiplication

Answer (score 0):

It's also true for the Laplace transformation and the (discrete time) Z-transformation. There is a general theory of transformations on groups for which this generalizes.