# Is the modulo-2 addtion of two random variables a convolution?

Tags: probability, convolution

Let's say we have two random discrete variables. Given an arbitrary element $y$ in $[0, 2^{n}-1]$, we compute the probability of $y$, where $y = x + b \mod 2^{n}$ by:

$$P(y) = \sum_{x=0}^{2^{n}-1} (P(x) \cdot P(b))$$

Am I right? But can we do the same if we consider $y = x \oplus b$? Namely, given an arbitrary element $y$ in $[0, 2^{n}-1]$, we compute the probability of $y$, where $y = x \oplus b$ by:

$$P(y) = \sum_{x=0}^{2^{n}-1} (P(x) \cdot P(b))$$

Or some other way?

Comment: Yes, you can do something similar for any Abelian group (see e.g. the first answer of  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577491/convolution-theorem-for-other-transforms )

Comment: Your sum needs to be over the elements where of $x$ and $b$ that give $y$. In both the sum and xor, it happens that there’s a unique $b$ for each $x$ and $y$ that does this, so setting $b$ accordingly would work.